# EF Core SaveChangesInterceptor primary key next value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, interceptor

I have implemented `SavingChangesAsync` from the `ISaveChangesInterceptor` interface. I am unable to determine what primary key for the record being saved because it has not been committed. I also tried the `SavedChangesAsync` function, but entity state is not set to `Added`, but `Unchanged`.

I tried the following methods:

```
public async ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SavingChangesAsync(DbContextEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var entry eventData.Context!.ChangeTracker.Entries().FirstOrDefault()
    
    console.write(entry.State); //equals Added
    console.write(entry.IsKeySet); //equals false
    console.write(entry.Entity.Id); //equals 0
    
    return await new ValueTask<int>(result);
}
```

The next primary key value for the record has not been set yet. I also used:

```
public async ValueTask<int> SavedChangesAsync(SaveChangesCompletedEventData eventData, int result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var entry eventData.Context!.ChangeTracker.Entries().FirstOrDefault()
    
    console.write(entry.State); //equals Unchanged
    console.write(entry.IsKeySet); //equals true
    console.write(entry.Entity.Id); //equals next integer value

    return await new ValueTask<int>(result);
}
```

I cannot get either the first event to fire with the new id or the second event to fire with the state value as `Added`

Answer (score -1):

That is the expected behavior when dealing with database generated Identity columns. At the time of `SavingChanges` you can query the change tracker to see what has been added, updated, or removed. At the time of SavedChanges, the changes have been committed so the change tracker will report them as Unmodified.

This means if you want to record something about an entity and include it's resulting ID when inserting, you will need to cache a reference to the added entities along with any "pre-commit" state if you are recording that during the SavingChanges event handler. Then in the `SavedChanges` handler, get the Id and details from the cached reference:

```
private class EntityChangeInfo
{ 
    public EntityState State { get; set; }
    public EntityEntry Entry { get; set; }
    // This is where you can add things like field data for updates, old value / updated value, etc.
}

private List<EntityChangeInfo> _entityChanges = new();
```

... Then in the SavingChanges()

```
_entityChanges.Clear();
var entry eventData.Context!.ChangeTracker.Entries().FirstOrDefault()

_entityChanges.Add(new EntityChangeInfo { entry.State, entry });
return await new ValueTask<int>(result);
```

Then in the SavedChanges()

```
foreach(var entityChange in _entityChanges)
{
   console.write(entityChange.State); // Original state when saving
   console.write(entityChange.Entry.Id); equals key that was assigned
}

_entityChanges.Clear();
```

The trouble with trying to fetch the ID prior to committing is that this could only possibly be done by EF applying a concurrency lock on the sequence the DB is using for the duration of the time from when you are querying to see what the next available ID is, and the change being committed. This poses problems in that you could get an ID value, but then the commit actually fails. So reporting/auditing on this should only be performed after the commit takes place.

Comment: I tried this on EF Core 8 and the proposed solution fails. State and Property original values of the Entry are in the reset state after SavingChanges occurs (despite the copying in the new DTO class - it still keeps the references).

Comment: The solution keeps a reference to the changetracker entity which will update after SaveChanges is called, anything you want to preserve you will need to copy out into the DTO itself within SavingChanges. In this example all I copied out was the original EntityState as-per the original question to make it available in the SaveChanges event. Copying the the reference does not persist the original pre-save state. If you want that you will need to clone a new instance to store in the DTO. EntityState is still an Enum in EF core so if you copy it out in SavingChanges it will not refresh.